# Function to Build New JSON Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, return, undefined

I have three JSON files.  My goal is to create a new one by combining data from them in a certain way.

At best I think I have the logic and syntax correct for combining the data (please correct me if wrong), but:

- I don't know precisely what, if anything, to `return` in the function.
- I don't know how to ultimately write the new file, even if the function is correct and complete.

The first obstacle is that, at least when I log the result of the call of the function, it returns *undefined*.  What's the problem?

Even if I get passed that, are the last two lines in my code completely and correctly the way to write the file?

I've attempted three variations, the only differences being what I am and am not returning.

**Code:**

```
var fs = require('fs');
const safeJsonStringify = require('safe-json-stringify');

var asanaProjects = require("C:/Users/GabrielRivera/asana/Asana Projects.json");
var asanaTasks = require("C:/Users/GabrielRivera/asana/Asana Tasks.json");
var asanaAttachments = require("C:/Users/GabrielRivera/asana/Asana Attachments.json");

function buildNewJSON() {
  return asanaProjects.map(project => {
    project.attachments = []
    asanaTasks.map(task => {
      if(project.items.includes(task.__object_id)){
        asanaAttachments.map(attachment => {
          if(task.attachments.includes(attachment.__object_id)){
            project.attachments.push(attachment)
            return project
          }
        })
      }
    })
  })
}

console.log(buildNewJSON())
var asanaData = safeJsonStringify(buildNewJSON());
fs.writeFile("asanaData.json", asanaData);
```

**Resulting JSON file:**  [null,null,null...]

**Code:**

```
function buildNewJSON() {
  return asanaProjects.map(project => {
    project.attachments = []
    asanaTasks.map(task => {
      if(project.items.includes(task.__object_id)){
        asanaAttachments.map(attachment => {
          if(task.attachments.includes(attachment.__object_id)){
            project.attachments.push(attachment)
          }
        })
      }
    })
  })
}

console.log(buildNewJSON())
var asanaData = safeJsonStringify(buildNewJSON());
fs.writeFile("asanaData.json", asanaData);
```

**Resulting JSON file:**  [null,null,null...]

**Code:**

```
function buildNewJSON() {
  asanaProjects.map(project => {
    project.attachments = []
    asanaTasks.map(task => {
      if(project.items.includes(task.__object_id)){
        asanaAttachments.map(attachment => {
          if(task.attachments.includes(attachment.__object_id)){
            project.attachments.push(attachment)
            return project
          }
        })
      }
    })
  })
}

console.log(buildNewJSON())
var asanaData = safeJsonStringify(buildNewJSON());
fs.writeFile("asanaData.json", asanaData);
```

**Resulting JSON file:**  undefined

Answer (score 0):

Update your `buildNewJson` method.

```
function buildNewJSON() {
  return asanaProjects.reduce(function(output,project){
        project.attachments = [];
      asanaTasks = asanaTasks.reduce(function(tasks,task){
         if(project.items.includes(task.__object_id)){
           asanaAttachments = asanaAttachments.reduce(function(attachments,attachment){
            if(task.attachments.includes(attachment.__object_id)){
               project.attachments.push(attachment);
            }
            attachments.push(attachment);
            return attachments;
           },[]);
         }
         tasks.push(task);
         return tasks;
      },[]);

      output.push(project);
      return output;
  },[]);
}
```